# DictWriter/Reader with csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to store data in a csv with `DictWriter` and read them after with another script with `DictReader`.

If the file exists, I just want to add the data, if not, I create it with the dict keys.
I'm doing this:

```
log_dict = {'X':list_X_data ,'Y':list_X_data,'time':list_time_data}
if( path.exists(file) ):
    with open(file, 'a') as csvwritefile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvwritefile, delimiter = ",")
            try:
                writer.writerows(zip(*[log_dict[key] for key in sorted(log_dict.keys())]))
                csvwritefile.close()
            except IOError:
                print("IO Error", file)
                csvwritefile.close()
else:
    with open(file, 'w') as csvwritefile:
            w = csv.DictWriter(csvwritefile, sorted(log_dict.keys()))
            try:
                w.writeheader()
            except IOError:
                print("IO Error", file)
                csvwritefile.close()
```

I didn't know how to store with `DictWriter` a `dict` with `list`s for values so I used `zip()` because I knew it was possible. Each second I append a data to each list and then store it every minute.
So I got something like that:

```
Heure      X    Y
16:12:16  0.9  4.5
16:12:17  0.8  0.9
16:12:18  0.0  0.9
```

I wonder how I can read this file with **DictReader** and get for exemple, **all the row of X** *or* just **the last 60 elements**.

I found this on anonther question but it outputs only the last line of the file:

```
w = DictReader(csvwritefile)
reader = DictReader(csvwritefile)
for line_dict in reader:
     X = line_dict['X']
```

(the output here will be `0.0`)

(Sorry for bad grammar or syntax...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do those two things with your data. I wasn't sure about the delimiter being used, so guess it was a tab character—but if it's something else you can easily change that.

```
import csv

filename = 'timing_data.csv'

# Get all the X values.
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    x_values = [row['X'] for row in reader]

print(x_values)  # -> ['0.9', '0.8', '0.0']
```

```
from collections import deque

filename = 'timing_data.csv'

# Get the last "N" X values.
N = 2
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    last_N_x_values = list(deque((row['X'] for row in reader), N))

print(last_N_x_values)  # -> ['0.8', '0.0']
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this tomorrow and let you know if it suits me